# Sinatra redirect with static html files

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

Ruby is new for me and I have a lame question.

I am serving web app with Sinatra and I am using static html files for front-end part.

Project structure:

- Project

  - models
  - routes
  - public

    - index.html
    - chat.html
  - app.rb

And I want to call redirect to chat.html when user is logged in the index.html

At the moment here is what I have:

```
   # some login stuff
   if first_user_found  && is_password_correct
     redirect to '/chat'
   else
     #do another thing
   end
```

and for for the /chat

```
get '/chat' do
  File.read('public/chat.html')
end
```

When I call localhost:4567/chat it load chat.html,
but when I try to login in the network tab /chat is called but no redirection is performed.

Could you please help?

Comment: Does `redirect '/chat'` yield the same result?

Comment: Could you post any output you're getting from Sinatra in your terminal?

Comment: Why not make your static pages `.html.erb` and stick them in the views folder? It works the same, since erb is basically html that you can put ruby in. Then you can do `erb :chat` instead of working with Files.

Comment: What are you using sinatra for if you only have static HTML?

Comment: From what I'm reading it seems that you're if statement is returning "false" and going into the else portion, skipping your redirect command.